# Jquery slide panel moves adjacent picture down

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slide

I'm using Jquery slide panels for some images.  The problem I'm having is when the slide panel shows it moves the image next to it down.  I do not want this to happen.  Is there a way to show the slider panel but not move the image next to it?  There are questions similar to this but there are no answers to them on the site.

Here's the jsfiddle without the image files:
**https://jsfiddle.net/amyspod/q2obknwt/**

Here's my code:

```
<div class="images">

          <div class="image1">
            <img class="myImg" id="heroimage" src="heros website.jpg" alt="www.heros.com" width="300" height="200">
            <div class="panel" id="hero">PSD to responsive website</div>
          </div>
          <div class="image2">
            <img class="myImg" id="oakimage" src="oak website.jpg" alt="www.oak.com" width="300" height="200">
            <div class="panel" id="oak">PSD to responsive website 2</div>
          </div>
        </div>


.myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 40px;
  }

  /*slider panels*/
.image1, .image2{
  display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 10%;

}
.panel {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: none;
}


$(document).ready(function(){

function slidepanel(x,y){
    $(x).mouseenter(function(){
        $(y).slideToggle("slow");
    });
     $(x).mouseleave(function(){
        $(y).slideToggle("slow");
    });
}

slidepanel("#oakimage", "#oak");
slidepanel("#heroimage", "#hero");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline (or inline-block) elements align to the baseline. Try this:

```
.image1,
.image2 {
    ...
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q2obknwt/1/)**

Also note that CSS classes, by design, are intended to be reusable. I see no reason to have two of them in this case, and they should have semantic values that describe their use or function.